# Dealing with array of complex numbers program

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to create a program that manipulates with arrays of complex numbers, my program has two classes, class that represents complex numbers and class that represents an array.

Here's the code that i created so far:

Complex.h

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>

class Complex
{
    friend class Array;
    double re, im;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Array&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Array&);

public:
    double getRe() const;
    double getIm() const;
    void setRe(double);
    void setIm(double);
    Complex operator[](int);
    Complex operator=(const Complex&);
    Complex operator+(const Complex&);
    Complex operator-(const Complex&);

private:
    Complex apply(const Complex&, const std::function <double(double, double)> &);
};
```

Array.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Complex.h" 
#include <functional>

class Array
{
    Complex *arr;
    int n;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Array&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Array&);

public:
    Array();
    Array(int);
    Array(const Array&);
    Array(Array&&);
    ~Array();
    Array& operator=(const Array&);
    Array& operator=(Array &&);
    Array operator+(const Array&);
//  Array operator-(const Array&);

private:
    Array& copy(Array&);
    Array& move(Array&);
    Array compute(const Array &,const std::function<Complex(Complex, Complex)> &f);

};
```

Complex.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Complex.h"

double Complex::getRe() const
{
    return re;
}

double Complex::getIm() const
{
    return im;
}

void Complex::setRe(double re)
{
    this->re = re;
}

void Complex::setIm(double im)
{
    this->im = im;

}
Complex Complex::operator[](int i)
{   
    Complex temp;
    temp.re = re;
    temp.im = im;

    return temp;
}

Complex Complex::operator=(const Complex &c)
{
    re = c.re;
    im = c.im;
    return *this;
}

Complex Complex::operator+(const Complex &c)
{
    *this = apply(c, [](double x, double y) { return x + y; });
    return *this;
}

Complex Complex::operator-(const Complex &c)
{
    *this = apply(c, [](double x, double y) { return x - y; });
    return *this;
}



Complex Complex::apply(const Complex &c, const std::function<double(double, double)> &f)
{
    re = re + c.re;
    im = im + c.im;

    return *this;
}
```

Array.cpp

```
Array::Array(int n)
{
    this->n = n;
    arr = new Complex[n];
}

Array::Array(const Array &a)
{
    this->n = a.n;
    arr = new Complex[n];
    arr = a.arr;
}

Array::Array(Array &&a)
{
    this->n = a.n;
    arr = a.arr;
    a.arr = nullptr;
}

Array& Array::operator=(const Array &a)
{
    this->n = a.n;
    arr = new Complex[n];
    arr = a.arr;
    return *this;
}

Array& Array::operator=(Array &&a)
{
    this->n = n;
    this->arr = a.arr;
    a.arr = nullptr;  
    return *this;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Array &a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.n; i++)
        out << a.arr[i].re << " +i" << a.arr[i].im;
    return out;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Array &a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.n; i++)
        in >> a.arr[i].re >> a.arr[i].im;   
    return in;
}

Array Array::operator+(const Array &a)            
{
    return compute(a, [](Complex x, Complex y) { return x + y; });

}
/*
Array Array::operator-(const Array &a)         
{
    return compute(a, [](Complex x, Complex y) { return x - y; });    
}
*/
Array Array::compute(const Array &a,const std::function<Complex(Complex , Complex)> &f)
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       arr[i] = f(arr[i], a.arr[i]);



    return *this;

}

Array::~Array()
{

    delete[] arr;
    n = 0;
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.h"
#include "Complex.h"


int main()
{

    Array a(2);       
    std::cin >> a;
    Array b;         
    b = a;          
    Array c(2);      
    c = a + b;
    std::cout << c;

    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

So this is what i have at the moment, i need to add that this worked just fine before, when in my `Complex` class i only had setters, getters, these fields and `Array` class as a friend, which means that i was doing indexing "manually" and operations `+` and `-` without overloading of corresponding operators in `Complex` class.

However, i had an idea that it would be better (and more in the spirit of oop) to overload the operators that i need for `Complex` class since code would be more readable.

However, even though i get the result i need, every time after execution of program, when i hit enter, error with destructor appears, i tried some debugging and it appears to me that problem appears when object `Array b` is "destructed", but i could not figure out what actually happens (and is b actually causing the problem in the first place).

NOTE: I've found some questions here related to complex arrays but non of them solved my problem.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Your `Array` move constructor and assignment operators are potentially leaking a lot of memory.

Comment: `arr = a.arr;` in your copy constructor is just copying the other `Array`'s pointer value. It's not copying the values contained in the array it points to. You now have two `Array` that use the same array and will both `delete` it. Most of your constructors and assignment operators contain significant logic errors. Use `std::vector<Complex>` instead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  can you explain me what is work with my move constructor? i new to this oop concepts.

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::complex<double>>`.  You issues will be reduced significantly, as well as your code size.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Specifically in `Array::Array(Array &&a)`, the problem is `a.n` is not zeroed, so `a` thinks it has elements but it's `arr` pointer is `nullptr`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thaks for advice, i'll surely keep that in mind in the future, however, as i said, i am still beginner in oop so i need to do this with as few libraries as possible (meaning, to create most of the stuff manually), in order to get better understanding of the problems in oop

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks for another response, i completely forgot about that, besides that, in copy constructor, am i supposed to go through whole array when copying one object to another in order to make an actual deep copy, is that what you meant in your second comment?

Comment: @cdummie Yes. But again, using `std::vector` is easier and safer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks again, as i said before, i'll keep that in mind, for sure!